# flask -- change behavior based on how the route is accessed

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

so let's say I have a route. If it is accessed by a user, I want to simply hand them a static json. However, if it is called by one of my scripts, I want to be able to say to do a different set of instructions. Namely, generate the json.

Eg, something like this (very pseudocode)

```
@app.route('/make_chart')
def make_chart():
  if #accessed by a user and not a script#:
    with open(app.config['JSON_PATH'], 'r') as j:
      return j
  elif #if my script is to call it using the route list#:
    dm = DataModel(app.config['CSV_PATH'])
    new_data = dm.do_some_stuff
    with open('some_name', 'w') as json_file:
      json.dump(new_data, json_file)
    return 200
```

how would this be possible? Something involving `__file__` or something like that?

Comment: Sounds like you want to separate out the routes then. If you are doing different things, why put them both in one function?

Comment: What Martijn said. If you have two use cases, separate them. If you want to change the *form* of the answer, i.e. return HTML to users and JSON to scripts, the standard way to do that is with Accept headers: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/45/